# default AUTH credentials mismatch Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

After running `php artisan make:auth` in my laravel project, I want to test some default functions. I MANUALLY entered data in my MySQL Database:

[image]

but when I try to login to my project using the above credentials:

[image]

I am sure that I have typed it as exactlly as indicated `secret123` but still unable to enter. Is there anything that I am missing? Or shall I do something to be able to manually enter data that matches credentials when I log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the password in the database is not plaintext (Big security no no).

You should try to hash your password with a Bcrypt hasher. I believe https://www.browserling.com/tools/bcrypt will work. Just fill in the password, rounds does not matter (as far as i know) and hash it! Then paste the has in the databse, then it should work for you!

Comment: Great suggest. This has done what I have wanted. Thank you.